# Is it possible to make VDB like the Bunny Cloud VDB example all in Blender 2.8?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine

Is it possible to make VDB volumes such as in this Redshift tutorial in Blender 2.8 ?

https://vimeo.com/201028766

[image]

I tried the principled volume shader from this tutorial : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lPAYX8z9i8M
It works ok using primitives & even Suzanne,
but it doesn't takes the general shape of the mesh and turns it into a cloud / smoke : it just make the clouds "contained" in it, with boundaries clearly visible.

And strangely, on others meshes, the clouds aren't even displayed at all. I tried messing with applying all transforms, scaling the textures on the material, with no luck.

I'd like to play with this type of render on complex meshes.

I guess this can be done in Redshift and exported as this particular bunny model is available on Openvdb's site and opens up fine in Blender 2.83 but i'd like to do it in Blender.

Comment: Make a colision object that looks like the bunny, then make an emitter inside of the bunny